# On a technical level, what happens when I enable bridge mode on a 2-in-1 gateway device?

Tags: networking, router, security, bridge-router

On a high level, I understand that bridge mode disables the NAT functionality of a router. In that case, the modem merely does it's job of converting the fiber optic/DSL/etc signals to digital signals and passes it on the the router.

However, how does this work on a technical level? i.e. How is the data being passed on, and what is the link between these two devices?

Can someone who has access to the modem also access the LAN?

Comment: Limit each post to a single question, and please do research first. Bridging should be a well documented system and you should be able to find the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> job of converting the fiber optic/DSL/etc signals to digital signals

It's all digital already (or analog, depending on perspective).

> how does this work on a technical level?

A bridge connects two networks at the data link layer (L2) and forwards in between by L2 address. The underlying physical layers and media can be very different, as long as their L2 protocols are similar enough to convert in between.

For example, an ISP runs PPPoA (point-to-point protocol over ATM) on the ADSL local loop. Then the bridge converts PPPoA frames into PPPoE ones (PPP over Ethernet) and of course, uses ADSL on the one and Ethernet on the other side as physical media. On the Ethernet side, another device (Ethernet WAN router, software router, PC client) could log in to a PPPoE session to connect to the Internet.

For a fiber uplink, PPPoE could be used as well on the WAN side, but it might also run plain IP, so the bridge works as a rather simple media converter.

> Can someone who has access to the modem also access the LAN?

Well, that depends on what you mean by *access to the modem* and by *access the LAN*. In bridge mode, the Ethernet side is still part of WAN, so you don't want to connect it to your private network directly. Put a router in between as a firewall. If you connect a PC directly, make sure its local firewall is active at all times.

However, *access the LAN* is likely meant as in *communicate with my private network devices* - since those likely use private addressing, anyone sending packets from WAN cannot use compatible addressing, so they'd have a hard time communicating.

On the other hand, it's possible that your LAN device cause information to leak out over the bridge that may provide useful information to a nearby attacker. Usually, the bridging modem and the ISP filter out compromising traffic but you don't want to rely on that.

In any case, WAN is to be considered hostile and you don't connect that without a firewall.

However, if *access to the modem* includes complete control over the modem/router, then yes, they can access your LAN as well. That's why you'd want to protect that device - configure a good password, disable the web GUI on the WAN side, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, very helpful! For a little context, I'm using a fiber optic modem (a Huawei HG8145V5) and my own personal router that connects to my computer via Ethernet. The modem is in bridge mode, and internet access is configured on my personal router via PPPoE. Is this secure enough? I have a firewall enabled on both the modem and router and also my Mac (will the modem's firewall even be used in this case?) I know that the Huawei modem currently has a RCE vulnerability with no fix yet, hence was wondering if compromising the modem is sufficient for someone to access my LAN.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be fine. Yes, all firewalls should be on at all times - the router firewall protects your network from outside attacks and the local firewalls protect each host from inside attacks (after infiltration/compromised hosts).

Comment: You need to fix vulnerabilities ASAP, or consider replacing the router. The RCE vulnerability likely only envolves the management web interface, so if you can deactivate that on the WAN side (shouldn't be active anyway) that should do - I'm assuming you don't have a bunch of 'wild' devices (guests, neighbors, IoT crap) on your LAN side that could attack the router from the inside...

Comment: Nope, no wild devices on the LAN. However, the RCE is in the modem and not the router. Can someone get to the modem if the router has no vulnerabilities? What about if there is a backdoor in the modem?

Comment: That depends on where the vulnerability is located (basically at which network layer). A modem is basically a layer-2 device/bridge, making an attack improbable, but it might have layer-3 management functions (TR-069 and such). Those are potentially open to the Internet unless they can be deactivated.